# DAX using current metrics cannot be desplayed

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, ssas-tabular

we had something devastating happened yesterday and we have no clue how it happened.

Our Power BI service is connected to a cube (a tabular model) in SSAS. So, we can only create measures off of the metrics that are already built in the cube.

Starting 4/17 around 3pm PST, a lot of the custom measures are not working anymore.

For example, we have metric in the cube called "Weekly Net Sales", it would work fine by itself. Bur if I create a new measure, "Weekly Net Sales New = [Weekly Net Sales]", which is literally calling the same measure. It is showing blank.

Long story short, the pre-existing measure will work fine. Once I start to modify it using CALCULATE and FILTER, or even calling the same measure by assign it a new name (the example above), the new measure will show blank or infinity.

Any help or if you ever experiencing the same thing and you have some insight that will be great! Super desperate here.

Thank you in advance!